# Como determinar a distancia final de um elemento em relação ao rodapé?

Tags: javascript, jquery

No caso em questão seria uma sidebar, que a partir de determinada altura de rolagem do topo, recebe position:fixed, porém conforme continua a rolagem ela fica escondida atrás do rodapé do site. Como eu poderia determinar que essa sidebar a partir de uma determinada distancia do rodapé parasse?(o rodapé possui cerca de 490px).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode fazer isso:

```js
$(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(){

    var div = $('#div');
    var space = $(document).height() - (div.offset().top + div.height());

        if(space <= 'quantidade que você quer'){
            div.css('position','relative');
        }    

    });
});
```

ai dentro do if você ajusta o css como quiser...

Comment: `div.offset().top * 2`? Aliás, por que dobrar o offset?

Comment: Corrigi, na verdade a soma é com o .height()!